# Azure Automation parameter with Dropdown

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I am working on a Azure automation workbook and would like to add a parameter that generates a dropdown list of values to be selected, similar to what happens when a Boolean variable is defined.

For Boolean parameters you get a dropdown with "default will be used", "true" and "false"

I would like to add something like "Database 1", "Database 2", "Database 3", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at the time of writing, as far as I'm aware. More over, adding a `validateset` to a parameter does absolutely nothing, as the runbook happily accepts the input and starts, despite the fact there is a validate set...

Comment: ValidateSet validates the input during the runbook execution, not in the parameters form prior to the execution.

Comment: which doesnt help at all :)